# Adding column with boolean values, based on a month in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-operator

I am trying to get a `1` for the row `2020-01`, only when the row crosses the column "Jan". And the same for every month:

- column `Feb` and row `2019-02` should also result in `1` and the rest of row `2019-02` should be `0`.
- column `Mar` and row `2019-03` should also result in `1` and the rest of row `2019-03` should be `0`.

Thus, all together, once per row, there should be a single `1` and a few `0`, based on the months. This is what I tried and the result is the screenshot, without the blue edit.

```
columns = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"]

for i in range(len(columns)):
    df[columns[i]] = df.TIME.astype(str).str[5] + df.TIME.astype(str).str[6]
df
```

The blue edit is the target.

[image]

I have tried a ternary operators like this:

```
for i in range(len(columns)):
    df[columns[i]] = 1 if (df.TIME.astype(str).str[5] + df.TIME.astype(str).str[6] == "01") else 0
```

and the error is:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You mean row, not column, am I right? What about the other months? Why is only Jan and Nov ? What about other years as well should Jan for 2019-01 be 1 or 0?

Comment: @CeliusStingher - I have edited to make it more understandable. It should be for every row, the year is irrelevant, the month matters only.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['TIME']).dt.strftime('%b').str.get_dummies().reindex(columns=columns, fill_value=0)` ..?

Comment: Sounds good @ChrisA !

Comment: @ChrisA - about 90% there, it lost my original columns... But, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.dt.stftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with `%b` formatter, [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back onto original DataFrame:

```
# Example setup
columns = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['2020-01', '2019-12', '2019-11', '2019-10', '2019-09']})    

df.join(pd.to_datetime(df['TIME']).dt.strftime('%b')
        .str.get_dummies()
        .reindex(columns=columns, fill_value=0))
```

[out]

```
      TIME  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov
0  2020-01    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1  2019-12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2  2019-11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
3  2019-10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
4  2019-09    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
```

---

#### Edit

I've only added this since you requested it specifically... Here is an example of how you could loop through a dataframe and columns to update values - again I'll just reiterate that this is not what I'd recommend personally and is very inefficient comapred with the above:

```
import datetime as dt

columns = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['2020-01', '2019-12', '2019-11', '2019-10', '2019-09']})

for c in columns:
    for i, t in df['TIME'].iteritems():
        if dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m').strftime('%b') == c:
            df.loc[i, c] = 1
        else:
            df.loc[i, c] = 0
```

Comment: @Vityata not sure about a looping method for this one. Generally not recommended though if a more "vectorized" solution exists

Comment: I see. Still, if you remember/invent a looping solution, consider adding another answer or editing this one. It would definitely help me understand the topic better.

Comment: @Vityata, I've added a looping solution since you requested it. Hope it gives you a better understanding :) cheers

Comment: Thanks. This looks really nice :)